# The general equation for a wave packet derivation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, fourier-transform

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet) it gives the general equation for a wave packet (and therefore for a wave?) to be:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}A(k)e^{i(kx-\omega t)} dk$$
I have been trying to derive this but have had no luck. The closest I get is:
$$f(x,t)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{u}_j(\omega)e^{2\pi i\omega x}d\omega\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{v}_j(\omega)e^{2\pi i\omega t}d\omega$$

But I don't know if this is right or where to go from here? So how can I derive the first equation?

Comment: What do you want to derive it *from*?

Comment: @ACuriousMind either the wave equation itself or the separated solutions to the wave equation

Comment: The wikipedia section leading up to this equation is the derivation.  This is basically superposition of all possible plane waves in a 1D system.

Comment: @XiaoleiZhu Yes but there is no proof that this must be the most general solution only a solution.

Comment: It is a general weighted sum of (an infinite number of, hence integral of) plane wave solutions to the wave equation, each with an amplitude $A$ which in general depends on the wavevector $k$ of the plane wave $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$

Comment: this is surely ***not*** the most general solution to the wave equation

Comment: @yuggib why is it not?

Comment: For example, given a function $A(0,x)$ and $\dot{A}(0,x)$ such that the first is in $L^2$ and the second with "inverse" of the derivative in $L^2$, then $A(t,x)=\cos \lvert\nabla\rvert t A(0,x) + \lvert\nabla\rvert^{-1} \sin \lvert\nabla\rvert t \dot{A} (0,x)$ is a solution of the wave equation.

Comment: @Joseph you have to read it in context.  This section is dealing with a specific wave equation, a wave in one dimensional system with no V term.    The author is trying to discuss dispersion, which would have little meaning if you do not expand it in plane waves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to the Schrödinger equation for a free particle is a plane wave, and because any combination of solutions is also a solution we can construct solutions by summing up plane waves.

The equation you quote is constructing a solution by Fourier synthesis. Since the plane wave function $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ is a solution we can use Fourier synthesis to sum up an infinite number of these solutions to produce any wavepacket we want. The function $A$ is just the Fourier transform of our desired wavepacket function $u$.

The equation is the most general form possible because we have complete freedom to choose $A$ so we can build any function $u$ that we want i.e. we can make the wavepacket envelope any shape we want. We can be confident that $u$ must be a solution to the Schrödinger equation because it is constructed from plane wave solutions to the Schrödinger equation.